# How can I get an ListView item from the (X,Y) position?

Tags: wpf, listview

I am dropping something in a ListView in WPF. I need to know the item in the (X,Y) position I am dropping. How can I do this?

---

The WPF ListView doesn't have GetItemAt. I return to my original problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done! Thanks to this article 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Drag_And_Drop_Sample.aspx

```
private int GetCurrentIndex(GetPositionDelegate getPosition)
{
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < clasesListView.Items.Count; ++i)
    {
        ListViewItem item = GetListViewItem(i);
        if (this.IsMouseOverTarget(item, getPosition))
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

private bool IsMouseOverTarget(Visual target, GetPositionDelegate getPosition)
{
    Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);
    Point mousePos = getPosition((IInputElement)target);
    return bounds.Contains(mousePos);
}

delegate Point GetPositionDelegate(IInputElement element);

ListViewItem GetListViewItem(int index)
{
    if (clasesListView.ItemContainerGenerator.Status != GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        return null;

    return clasesListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListViewItem;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hoops, sorry. This should work fine:

```
FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;

ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)listView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(element.DataContext);
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the [GetItemAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.getitemat.aspx) function. You may also need to call the [PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) function before the GetItemAt since you need to work with [client coordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229598.aspx).

Comment: The WPF ListView doesn't have GetItemAt. I return to my original problem.

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote because this answer came up when I was actually looking for a winforms related question.  Thanks for the help even though you were off-topic.